# How to get all the divs within a div with certain id using querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to get all the divs inside a div whose id is dd-elements

And I am using

```
var dragElementsList = document.querySelectorAll("#dd-elements div");
```

is this correct syntax? AFAIK Its correct syntax and in the nodelist I get 9 elements but all are in undefined state when I try to alert them.

```
for(var j=0; j<dragElementsList.length; j++)
{
    alert(dragElementsList[i]);
}
```

Where is the mistake? Will be very thankful for quick response.

Comment: do all divs has the same ID?

Comment: You are using `j` as the iteration counter, but pass `i` as the offset when alerting the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this,Use j instead of i

```
 for(var j=0; j<dragElementsList.length; j++)
{
   alert(dragElementsList.item(j).id); //get element id
}
```

**querySelectorAll** returned NodeList will contain all the elements in the document.

The nodes in the NodeList can be accessed through their index number (starting from 0).

**Reference**

querySelectorAll : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll

nodelist : http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodelist.asp

Comment: @VickyGonsalves sorry for that it was by mistake

Answer (score 1):

You have used `i` instead of `j`

```
   var dragElementsList = document.querySelectorAll("#dd-elements div");
    for(var j=0; j<dragElementsList.length; j++)
    {
       alert(dragElementsList[j].id);  //will give you element's id

    }
```